# How can I, in Visual Studio 2013, get a source control check-in list similar to that in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, checkin

Back in Visual Studio 2010, selecting "Source control" -> "Check in" would open a separate window that listed all checked-out files, with those under the selected node (or the currently open file in the case of going through the File menu) initially selected for checking in. This list was sortable by clicking on the column headers, making it easy to sort the list by any of the fields listed. (Particularly, I found sorting by edit type to be very useful.)

A very similar dialog (actually, I think it is essentially the same one, save for the graphical icons being different to match the revamped UI style) can be accessed in VS2013 through the source control merge wizard by selecting "Selected changesets", right-clicking on a changeset in the resultant list, and choosing "Changeset details". This dialog even has the advanced feature that it is *fully resizable* according to the preferences of the user and the needs at the time. But that, of course, is only available after the changes have been checked in.

[image: Details for Changeset dialog in VS2013]

The pending changes/check-in view in VS2013 is just a tree view in the "Pending Changes" window, which can be set to table view but doesn't separate pending change type from file name, making the table view almost, but not entirely, as useless as the corresponding tree view. The view in 2013 also has the serious drawback that while the window (whether docked or free-floating) can be enlarged, I can find no way to enlarge the list of changes vertically, so I am stuck looking at 14 files at a time on the 1920x1200 monitor. While check-ins should generally be small, sometimes check-ins affecting a large number of files are just unavoidable. (Like right now I am looking at a merge affecting a total of 840 files because of a refactoring effort.)

Which leads me to my question. **Is there any way to get a dialog similar to that in VS2010 for *checking in* files when running VS2013?**

I'm open to suggestions involving paid-for add-ons, but a free solution (whether it can be done through an add-on, or some configuration setting I have simply failed to find) might be an easier sell.

Comment: I completely agree. What do you think about this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7257897-allow-filtering-on-change-type-or-restore-change